# background image width and height to fit all media - unable to make it work

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I had created a fluid layout (to build a RWD website) and in my design there are some images which needs to be shown as background image, as there will be text shown above the image (over lapping it).

Now in 'fluidLayouts.css' file, it shows:

img, object, embed, video { max-width: 100%;}

I have edited to: 
img, object, embed, video 
{max-width: 100%;
  height:auto;}

Here i have added "height:auto;" but nothing happens to the background image, i don't see it fully, nor it re-sizes to any media which are mobile, tab or desktop.

How do i set a height for an background image for it to be scaled automatically to any media? Am using background image to the website design overall.

Comment: `background-size: 100% auto;` is perhaps what you are looking for.

Comment: @abhitalks added "background-size: 100% auto;" to the background-image line...but in browser the image is not being displayed, only the width is visible.

Comment: Add relevant markup and css code in the question, clearly describing what you want, what you have tried and what is not working. It is very difficult to understand what you are after.

Comment: okay, i will get back on this one.

Comment: Meanwhile, you can have a look at this to understand what I was saying: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/x3r9d8k3/

Comment: Thanks abhi....will check that link!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two things here: `img`, `object`, `embed` and `video` are block elements that behave like they are supposed to (being `block` elements).

`background-image` is just a CSS property applied to an element (with some certain width and height that is calculated by yout CSS layout) but `background-image` itself **does not** and **can not** influence the size of an element.

Here's the fiddle for you to see how different settings behave: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1y05gcy/)

You have two options.

First one is to use regular `img` tag and put the content above it using relative positioning.

Second one is to use `background-image` and either just apply `background-size: cover` - this will not however keep original proportions of an image, or and `background-size: cover` plus width declaration (whatever you like, fixed pixels, 100%, doesn't matter) and use a `padding-bottom` hack to extend this div to desired aspect ratio. So if your image is 500/300 than your padding-bottom needs to be (300/500)*100 = 60%.

Comment: I got what you are saying....But then, how do i solve the issue of the background-image being shown with the exact size and it being re-sized for any media?